# How to insert a document and return the same in MongoDB in a single database operation in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to add a document in a MongoDb and return the same. I know I can use two operation to do it. i.e.

1. Insert the document and retrieve _id value.
2. Retrieve the document using the _id.

Is there any way I can do it in a single database trip?

I am using MongoDB Java Driver 3.12.8

Comment: Do you get a response from the db when you do the Insert? Maybe that contains the _id value? Guessing ofc as I have no idea

Comment: no, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.insertOne

Comment: @GamingFelix I am providing my own _id, hence there is no problem for me. insertOne returns void.

Comment: I must have read your question wrong. But yeah if you don't get a response then I wouldn't know. Probably best to dig through the documentation